# directory structure for fxgl app (specifically .tmx files)

Tags: java, tmx, fxgl

I've been following an older tutorial for fxgl that uses the tiled software to create maps (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37wfF9GW1vQ&t=9s). I've looked online for anything about what the directory structure should look like, but every time I try to run it I get the error: Asset not found: tutorial.tmx. The line of code that runs this is `FXGL.setLevelFromMap("tutorial.tmx");` under the initGame() function. I've been using Maven to build the project, and my current directory structure is as follows: [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6VjF.png). Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In the file "module-info.java" the first line needs to have the modifier `open` before the `module *class name* {`